# What is context window size?

Tags: rnn, machine-translation

I am trying to implement a recurrent neural network machine translation system, and I am just learning the things.

I am creating a word embedding matrix. In order to do that, I should know my vocabulary size, dimension of the embedding space, and context window size?

What is context window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A context window applies to the number of words you will use to determine the context of each word. Like of your statement is "the quick brown fox"  a context window of two would mean your samples are like (the,quick) and ( the, brown). Then you slide one word and your samples become  (quick, the ), (quick, brown) and (quick fox) and so on. I would suggest reading up this [word 2vec tutorial](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/&ved=0ahUKEwieoaeF3tDRAhVKQo8KHRf-CHkQFggyMAI&usg=AFQjCNFRBSxWBWA8Qw1C5rn0pvyHEwjNqw&sig2=FuVfcDwAJBnmD_UiUHwGmg) to understand the training method and terminology.